# dreamhost+django: cannot get domain name using site framework

Tags: python, django, web, dreamhost, domain-name

In my view i execute `Site.objects.get_current().domain` but the result is empty string.
So, how can i get the domain name to compose right url?

Hosting is dreamhost.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you're running on a VPS/dedicated server? Do you have the site name set properly?

Comment: Is your default site actually configured with a domain name? By default, it should be `example.com`. Just to clarify, all it should be doing is reading a Site object's domain field - not any kind of magical guessing of domain name.

Comment: i'm running on VPS server. if, from admin section, i verify the sites in database, both on localhost and on the dreamhost vps i can see one site, named example.com. But on localhost the result is 'localhost', on vps is '' (empty string). So probably that i hadn't configured site name properly on dreamhost vps, how to do it?

Comment: If this is a configuration problem, ask Dreamhost, or ask on their support forums. That said, realise that Dreamhost provide very old versions of software, so you may also need to upgrade to recent python and django.

Comment: In dreamhost now i have version 1.2.1 of django. So i will upgrade to version 1.3.1, but i'm not sure that it will resolve the problem.

Comment: I have resolved. No update, but killing the old process now it works fine. Sorry for time lost for this stupid topic.

Comment: Can you post the answer and close the topic please ? I've just read your topic in vain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem waas that it was executing the old instance of webapp (that didn't use sites module) So i have resolved with pkill python command.